# Consume events in delphi DLL  that can be used by VB6

Tags: delphi, events, vb6

I have created bandwidth monitoring function in delphi dll, where i need to raise a event if any bandwidth transfer occurred. similarly i need to declare the delphi dll in vb and consume the dll event. Any ideas welcome

Comment: What kind of object is it? If it is a COM object firing COM events, then you will be able to capture them. If it's something internal to Delphi, then probably not.

Comment: yes com object firing com events

Comment: It will work like any other COM object then - add a reference to it, declare a reference to it in your code using the `WithEvents` modifier, then you should be able to add event handlers (tip: use the listboxes at the top of the code window to select the object, then select the event.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want an IDispatch interface, which will mean that you (a) define a class in Delphi, (b) use dual interfaces (COM vtable + DISPATCH). And (c) expose that COM object to your VB object.  (d) In VB you also define an IDispatch type COM interface, and you pass that interface in as a parameter.  I would call such an IDispatch interface an INotify.

there are actually standard com interfaces often used in OLE Automation, like the connection point container, that you might want to look into.  See this article:

http://www.gtro.com/delphi/comevents_e.php